# PCIE USB card not working. What's the missing "... resource 0 [io ...]" line in dmesg meaning?

Tags: drivers, io, dmesg, pci

Problem with 4x USB controller PCIE cards seems to be not correctly installed.

Situation: We want to use USB Vision cameras with USB adapter cards, providing as much bandwidth as possible. So we tried two different card types: ASMedia xy and Renesas uPD720202, where market is dominated by ASMedia and it was really hard to get a few of the Renesas cards.

The problem: The ASMedia Card is partly working. Usb devices like external SSD drives are usable (with high transferrates), but when using a camera, it stops after a few frames with some DMA error. The camera uses a BULK mode. Googeling for some hours shows, that ASMedia chip seems to have some firmware bugs or whatever, so we dropped the idea of using that card. The ASMedia did work on no tested PC in combination with the camera).
Trying the Card with Renesas chips, it is working perfectly on a ThinkCentre pc but not on the target hardware, a Supermicro Server. Both are using the same OS (Ubuntu 18.04, Kernel 5.4.0-97-generic). The Server has much more RAM, GPUs, etc.

Here's the link to the ThinkCentre where it's working: https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=c945332cad

Here's the link to the Server (not working): https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=f0c1c16098

We tried a lot of stuff in the wild (from random google hits where problems with the renesas card were solved), like autosuspend off, kernel updates, different Ubuntu versions etc.. Nothing helped, so I compared the dmesg of both systems.

The only real difference I could spot a missing line during initialization (?) of the card. Please ignore the fact, that the ThinkCentre is showing 4x the uPD720202 controller but the server only 3x. My colleague says it showed 4x in each other run, but unfortunately I now only have the 3x log.

Here's the difference I could spot:
In the ThinkCentre dmesg there is this block:

```
[ 0.268577] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 0 [io 0x2000-0x2fff]
[ 0.268578] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 1 [mem 0xdf300000-0xdf3fffff]
[ 0.268578] pci_bus 0000:03: resource 2 [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff 64bit pref]
[ 0.268579] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 0 [io 0x3000-0x3fff]
[ 0.268580] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 1 [mem 0xdf200000-0xdf2fffff]
[ 0.268580] pci_bus 0000:04: resource 2 [mem 0xd0200000-0xd03fffff 64bit pref]
[ 0.268581] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 0 [io 0x4000-0x4fff]
[ 0.268582] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 1 [mem 0xdf100000-0xdf1fffff]
[ 0.268582] pci_bus 0000:05: resource 2 [mem 0xd0400000-0xd05fffff 64bit pref]
[ 0.268583] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 0 [io 0x5000-0x5fff]
[ 0.268584] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 1 [mem 0xdf000000-0xdf0fffff]
[ 0.268584] pci_bus 0000:06: resource 2 [mem 0xd0600000-0xd07fffff 64bit pref]
```

while on the server I see this block:

```
[ 10.247535] pci_bus 0000:83: resource 1 [mem 0xd3600000-0xd36fffff]
[ 10.247538] pci_bus 0000:83: resource 2 [mem 0x390000000000-0x3900001fffff 64bit pref]
[ 10.247540] pci_bus 0000:84: resource 1 [mem 0xd3500000-0xd35fffff]
[ 10.247542] pci_bus 0000:84: resource 2 [mem 0x390000200000-0x3900003fffff 64bit pref]
[ 10.247545] pci_bus 0000:85: resource 1 [mem 0xd3400000-0xd34fffff]
[ 10.247547] pci_bus 0000:85: resource 2 [mem 0x390000400000-0x3900005fffff 64bit pref]
[ 10.247550] pci_bus 0000:86: resource 1 [mem 0xd3300000-0xd33fffff]
[ 10.247552] pci_bus 0000:86: resource 2 [mem 0x390000600000-0x3900007fffff 64bit pref]
```

You can see that there is an io line for each of the resources, which is missing in the server dmesg.

What is this line for? What are likely reasons for those lines missing? How to debug? Is this even the right hint to solve the problem?

Btw: The cameras are working perfectly on any of the internal/native USB controllers of that server.

Thanks for any help/idea.

Edit:

USB adapter cards are:
DELOCK 89008

https://www.reichelt.de/de/de/pcie-x4-4-x-extern-usb-3-0-typ-a-delock-89008-p288774.html?r=1

Renesas Technology Corp.    4x uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller

Driver is xhci_hcd from the kernel, if I understand it right:

```
Device: 83:00.0
Class:  USB controller [0c03]
Vendor: Renesas Technology Corp. [1912]
Device: uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller [0015]
PhySlot:    0-1
Rev:    02
ProgIf: 30
Driver: xhci_hcd
NUMANode:   1
```

Driver information (please mind, that the system has been reinstalled several times between the hw-probe and this one):

```
lspci -nk

60:00.0 0c03: 1912:0015 (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
61:00.0 0c03: 1912:0015 (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
62:00.0 0c03: 1912:0015 (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
63:00.0 0c03: 1912:0015 (rev 02)
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

```
lspci -v (only one port)


60:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Physical Slot: 0-1
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 25, NUMA node 0
    Memory at c5e00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

except the `NUMA node 0` (only on server) there is no difference between Server (not working) and ThinkCentre (working).

```
03:00.0 USB controller: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller (rev 02) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Physical Slot: 0
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 17
    Memory at df300000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [70] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [90] MSI-X: Enable+ Count=8 Masked-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [150] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
```

Comment: First you should give us exact model and specs of the USB card.  Next I would start with the drivers.  What version are you using?  Did you try multiple versions of the drivers?

Comment: @tukan I added the information, but I'm not sure whether I got the driver information correctly. If not, how to find/read it?

Comment: If you could add the output of `lspci -v` and `lspci -nk` for that card. `dmesg` would be helpful for that card too.

Comment: Could you try to add `pci=nomsi` to your grub's booting parameters?

Comment: added `lspci -v` and `lspci -nk`

Comment: Please run `lspci -v` again as root

Comment: @mashuptwice done. Also added the lspci -v of the ThinkCentre.

Comment: Please boot your system without MSI as I suggested above. It should help.

Comment: @tukan thank you, I will try that as soon as possible (only remote access in the next days).

Comment: If pci=nomsi not helps, try the  numa=off. Just a tipp. https://access.redhat.com/solutions/23216

Comment: You might wanna try debug with `dmesg -Hx`.

Comment: So what is the result?  It is really impolite to ask for help but don't tell us what happened.

Comment: @tukan in panic we switched to Windows in between and now we don't have the time to test, because of a deadline. We will continue the tests in the beginning of april and I will tell the results.

Comment: I see.  Well with Windows you will have even harder time.  I wish you luck.  Please tell us then when you have time

Comment: @tukan thank you, I really appreciate your help and I am really looking forward to continue those tests.

Comment: @tukan sorry, we couldnt continue the tests. Our project management was lucky to find another 4xUSB card available on the market which worked out of the box: PEXUSB3S44V from StarTech (Renesas UPD720202 Chip - so the same chip...). In between we also tested thunderbolt USB Hubs, which had similar problems on the server as the DELOCK cards.

Comment: @Micka I see, well it is pitty we could not know the result, but you got lucky :).